# Indexing of very large Table - Base information on performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

I have a table with 30.000.000 rows and having heavily performance problems. In the beginning - when I didn´t know that as many rows will be in - I created an index only on two fields of at least 23 at all. This two fields are of varchar type. Twenty of the fields are varchar and text types and three of them are of int type.

**My first question**:

How can I really improve the all over performance of the database? Found so many tips but none of it really worked. The bad performance causes following problems:

1) Whether I can create any more indexes nore can I copy the 30.000.000 rows to an empty table with created indexes for all fields (if I try one of each, it takes many many hours untill I break the query and nothing happens at all)

2) The performance of single searches in the frontend is very slow. If some more clients are connected at once they are waiting very long, just to get a timeout at the end.

Some code:

```
"SELECT *, MATCH(item_query) AGAINST ('\"".$query."\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
 FROM items 
 WHERE MATCH(item_query) AGAINST ('\"".$query."\"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND item_address LIKE '%".$where."%' AND item_type = '".$what."' AND item_language = '".$_SESSION['language']."' AND item_country = '".$_SESSION['country']."' ORDER BY score DESC"
```

This statement is used when a user types a search-query into the frontend. item_query id indexed, the other fields are not (yet).

I even created a script that should read 1000 datasets, writting it to the new full indexed table and do this on and on until no more data coming. But with no success... The script hang 10 minutes before I got a 500 server error.

When I use the GUI (SqlYog) to view data and I limit the results to 1000 or even 5000 rows, it works perfect - takes a moment but works good. So the table seems to be ok.

**My second question**:

As soon as I found any solution for the indexing problem, how could I improve the sql statement viewed above???

Thank you in advance for any ideas,

Best regards, Ingmar

Comment: You've tagged this question as both "MySQL" and "SQL Server". Which is it? What version?

Comment: Sorry, MySql 5.x as I know (I think 5.5 or 5.6)

Comment: I installed it one year ago with apt-get on debian, that´s why I don´t know exactly now. If you want to know exactly, I have to connect to the server. Tables are MyISAM...

Comment: Running on your local computer, not a remote computer?

Comment: Not related, but use [mysqli](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) prepared statements instead of concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

> When I use the GUI (SqlYog) to view data and I limit the results to
>   1000 or even 5000 rows, it works perfect - takes a moment but works
>   good. So the table seems to be ok.

Use `CHECK TABLE table-name` to check tables for problems. Read [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/check-table.html) first.

One rule of thumb for performance is to index every column used in a WHERE clause.  So you'd index "item_type", "item_language", and "item_country", at the very least. I presume the full-text column "item_query" already has a full-text index; your wildcard criteria for "item_address" can't use an index. Compound indexes might be useful.

To isolate the problem, try removing the criteria for "item_address". Also learn to use and interpret [MySQL's EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html).

I have a table with 30 million rows here. It takes about 10 minutes to create an index on a varchar(35) column.  My computer is nothing special.

If you're going to load data into a new table, you're probably better off creating the table with *no* indexes, no primary key, and no foreign keys; then loading the data; and finally creating the indexes, primary key, and foreign keys.

You might also try [dumping the database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) and reloading it on a different computer. (Or the same computer, if necessary.)

Comment: Hi Mike, do you think it makes any sense to use MATCH AGAINST on every other fields to?

Comment: Not if you know the values you're searching for.